# Update Azure Batch application from build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-batch

How can one update an Azure Batch application with a task in a build pipeline on AzureDevOps?

Comment: This document should give you a brief overview of using a build pipeline to upload Applications to Batch with multiple different versions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-ci-cd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) (use task version 1.0 which is based on the 2.0 az cli) in your pipeline and use the [az batch application](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/batch/application?view=azure-cli-latest) commands to update your Application Packages.

Comment: It's actually the `az batch application package create` (even though you only update).